# Java - XMPP - I need some document or tutorial for it

Tags: java, xmpp

i found XMPP on google (i need create a application IM look like Yahoo or Live or Pidgin), i need write XMPP Server and Client but i don't know how to write it?

because of it, it need some document or tutorial help me write server and client interactive with my database.

Thank you

Best Regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try writing server components with [Whack](http://www.igniterealtime.org/downloads/index.jsp) framework. I've blog about using Whack [here](http://oneminutedistraction.wordpress.com/) ([part1](http://oneminutedistraction.wordpress.com/2010/09/28/developing-xmpp-components-the-setup/), [part2](http://oneminutedistraction.wordpress.com/2010/10/08/developing-xmpp-components-the-service-2/), [part3](http://oneminutedistraction.wordpress.com/2010/10/20/developing-xmpp-components-some-tips/)).

Answer (score 3):

Either you can write your own or use the already proven open source libraries ready to be used. Look this post [Good XMPP Java Libraries for server side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177514/good-xmpp-java-libraries-for-server-side)

If you are looking for tutorials, articles etc then go to [xmpp.org](http://xmpp.org/) or go to this post [Good tutorials on XMPP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092534/good-tutorials-on-xmpp)