# Multiplayer turn based game in android

Tags: android, network-programming, multiplayer

I'm trying to develop a multiplayer game on Android..close to TIC TAC TOE game ( 2 player turn based game).I'm new to the whole multiplayer game development thing, so i would like to get some clarification on few thinkgs..

1. Do I need a cloud server ( e.g. servers like smartfoxserver,Photonserver)  to handle a turn based game ?
2. For a simple game like the above one, should i have to use an open source SDK(like skiller) to make it multiplayer or should i have to write server & client programming myself?
3. Are there any open source SDK's available apart from skiller, (openfiet & scoreloop, based on my google search, i guess they don't support turn based game stuff on their SDK)

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No, for a simple 2-player game a cloud server is completely unnecessary (sockets as mentioned by user104... could be an option). You might want to consider one anyway, in order to keep better track of game activity and limit cheating, but server-side obviously has a cost.

Rather than purchasing expensive server solutions, incidentally, I would consider looking at CAAS providers such as Stackmob, Parse, Kinvey, etc. Or simply using AppEngine or the Amazon cloud.

1. If any good open-source SDK existed, it would obviously be an interesting option. However, I do not think one does (I would read carefully the Skiller license before starting to do anything with that library).
2. Not that I know of. AndEngine has a multiplayer component of some sort. MAGES was an early multiplayer framework that has since been discontinued.

Comment: I think this is close to solving my problem for turn based game. I'm actually looking at ASMACK for android these days. I found this on SO, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263991/android-two-player-game-to-be-played-in-internet , i guess i didn't search properly before posting it :)

Answer (score 2):

I am currently writing a multiplayer turn based android game and I am writing the client/server myself. I have seen the api's of skiller and the rest but I wanted to challenge myself. It is quite involving but as I said a challenge to gain more experience. I have written my server in php and my client side of course in java. If you are able to get your timing, and identification right, things start getting smooth.

Answer (score 0):

I think that in case of such a simple game you can avoid of using server. Here's an example of phone-to-phone app, where one phone is the server
http://www.android10.org/index.php/articlesgeneralprogramming/262-socket-programming-in-android-applications