# Two player android tutorial (bluetooth/internet)

Tags: android

I'm looking for a two player game tutorial using android.
I really have no idea where to start. I've read this [forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263991/android-two-player-game-to-be-played-in-internet), but what i need is a sample code because i don't understand anything on it. 
Any suggestions where I can find sample codes (really simple) to follow?

Thank you.

Comment: why don't you use UDP for this purpose.. It's very simple for simple data transfer..